# Mostrar dados dinamicamente

Tags: javascript

Tenho esse ajax que faz a requisição de uma lista de nomes para mim.. este é o código em javascript puro:

```
 function listagem() {

 var lista = {

idUsuario: document.querySelector(".campo").value,
token: document.querySelector(".campo-token").value
};

let xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
var variavel = document.querySelector(".token-servico").innerHTML;
xhr.open("POST", "http://listAll", true);
xhr.setRequestHeader("Content-type", "application/json");
xhr.setRequestHeader("Authorization", "Bearer " + variavel);

xhr.addEventListener("load", function () {



  if (xhr.status == 200) {

    window.sessionStorage.setItem('lista', xhr.responseText);

    var lista = window.sessionStorage.getItem('lista');

    lista = JSON.parse(lista);

    let x = document.querySelector('#body')

    lista.map(item => {

      x.innerHTML += '<tr><td>'+ item.nome +'</td></tr>'
    });

}
```

Porém, do jeito que está a listagem aparece só depois que eu clico num botão. O que posso fazer para que a lista apareça assim que a página for acessada?

Grato a quem responde

Comment: Apenas isso: `window.onload = listagem;`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Altere a função `listagem()` para `document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function(event){`, que irá executar o código quando a página for carregada:

Sem mencionar que há trechos no seu código sem fechamento que corrigi abaixo:

```
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function(){

   var lista = {

      idUsuario: document.querySelector(".campo").value,
      token: document.querySelector(".campo-token").value
   };

   let xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
   var variavel = document.querySelector(".token-servico").innerHTML;
   xhr.open("POST", "http://listAll", true);
   xhr.setRequestHeader("Content-type", "application/json");
   xhr.setRequestHeader("Authorization", "Bearer " + variavel);

   xhr.addEventListener("load", function () {

      if (xhr.status == 200) {

         window.sessionStorage.setItem('lista', xhr.responseText);

         var lista = window.sessionStorage.getItem('lista');

         lista = JSON.parse(lista);

         let x = document.querySelector('#body')

         lista.map(item => {

            x.innerHTML += '<tr><td>'+ item.nome +'</td></tr>'
         });
      }
   });

});
```